# Problem Using An 9 degree of freedom IMU with Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: arduino, atmega, imu

I am using an IMU from sparkfun that posses an atmega328p.
I upload the source code and everything works fine when using the Arduino IDE.
 I created a .sh script to read from the terminal in ubuntu.

When I read the scripts to initialize the communication with the arduino using the stty command it works, but when I try to retrieve the data the process keeps running until I hit ctrl+z to stop the process and I get trash data.
In order for the scripts to work I need to open the serial monitor in arduino and send one command. Then I can use the .sh file that I created to run and read the data from the IMU from the terminal without problem. I want to be able to run everything without having to use the arduino since the system is going to be running in a computer and everything will be called from a Linux terminal.

If someone has an idea and can help me to solve this problem I will be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Arduino sends a bunch of `NUL` bytes after it resets. Also the buffers of your PC will probably have data from previous sessions in them, you have to flush these. Also I chose to start using frames with a preamble for communication between PC and Arduino. That way you can easily lock onto the data stream. I've written a couple of Perl scripts for this: [cat_ttyUSB](http://wirespeed.xs4all.nl/mediawiki/index.php/Cat_ttyUSB)

Comment: Thanks for that tip and Those scripts, they will help me by guiding me  to improve and solve most of my problem. Now my main problem seems to be that the script I have keeps running even after I receive my data, how can I stop it without hitting crtl+z every time in order to be able to send another command.

Comment: You're on Linux I understood from your question? Hit `Ctrl`+`C`